# format number in input box with two decimal place

Tags: html, angular

I have below input control in my html

```
 <input id="inputcntrl" type="text" value="{{(mynumber) | number:'2.2-2'}}" [(ngModel)]="mynumber" (blur)="validatemynumber()" />
```

As you can see I am formatting input text to make sure it has two decimal values. It does work correctly when user enters the value in input box. onBlur event I am checking the value entered by user and if it is not within the range (min >mynumber>max) then I am setting mynumber with min value. Problem is mynumber displays min value with no formatting. forex: If min valule is 10 then input box should display 10.00 but it displays only 10..any idea how can I fix this? I am using angular2

Update: I think problem in my case is with somehow related to binding..When I update mynumber from my component and the new value is reflected in UI but its formatting is lost. mynumber variable is of type number. I need to find a way to update value with formatting from component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format `mynumber` at your component with an **angular way**, try using built-in **[DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)** at your component(*the same as number pipe used at your template*).

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'

this.mynumber = this.decimal.transform(this.mynumber, '2.2-2');
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UZQa9PYef4a6sfeFjOGY?p=preview)**

Comment: mynumber is of type number and transform returns string...so it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try `mynumber.toFixed(2)`

```
<input id="inputcntrl" type="text" value="{{mynumber.toFixed(2)}}" [(ngModel)]="mynumber" (blur)="validatemynumber()" />
```

Here is a  reference documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: nope it does not work...infact now it is not formatting even when user enters the value